# Default Start Time and Expiry time for an Account Level SAS Token

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I created an account level SAS token programmatically using Azure SDK.While Creating SAS token, under Shared Access Account Policy settings, I didn't explicitly select the Shared Access Expiry Time and Shared Access Start Time.What will be the default Time Duration for the SAS token expiration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What will be the default Time Duration for the SAS token expiration

If you did not define the start time for a SAS token that means the token will become effective immediately.

Similarly if you did not define the expiry time that means the token will never expire (or expire on 9999-12-31 23:59:59).

Comment: do you know where is the official document about the default expiry time?